# Unbiased estimators of a transformed Poisson

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, poisson-distribution, unbiased-estimator, truncation

So the question I have is$:$

> Let $X$ follow a Poisson distribution with mean $\mu$, except that $X=0$ cannot be observed; this gives a random variable $Y$ which has a truncated Poisson distribution
>
> $$P(Y=y)=\frac{\mu^ye^{-\mu}}{(1-e^{-\mu})y!}, y=1,2,...$$
>
> Suppose we want to estimate the probability $$P(X>0)=1-e^{-\mu}=q(\mu)\,.$$
>
> Show that an unbiased estimator of $q(x)$ is $r(y)$ where $r(y)=0$ if $y$ is odd, and $r(y)=2$ if $y$ is even. Is this a reasonable estimator of $q(\mu)?$

So I want to first see if this is unbiased and then check if its the best unbiased estimator using exponential family theory.  But I don't know how to begin. I guess I should start by finding $P(Y=2n)$?

I'm not good with transformations I have realized from this course can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

> I guess I should start by finding $P(Y=2n)$

I'd think so, though there's probably another way to do it. That's what I'd start with anyway.

One approach to doing that:

First pull the terms that don't change with $n$ out the front.

Note that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^{2k}}{(2k)!}=\cosh z\,\!$; see the wikipedia page "List of mathematical series", specifically the section on [Trigonometric, inverse trigonometric, hyperbolic, and inverse hyperbolic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series#Trigonometric.2C_inverse_trigonometric.2C_hyperbolic.2C_and_inverse_hyperbolic_functions).

You'll want to subtract the first term from both sides and rewrite $\cosh$ in terms of $\exp$, but that should get you somewhere.